# Customize HTTP codes and error message in JBoss AS 7

Tags: http, tomcat, jboss, status

can anyone tell me how i can customize http codes and reasonphrase in JBoss AS 7?

basically i have a REST webservice that returns a nonstandard status code '499' with reasonphrase 'app error'

In `standalone.xml`, I set the `org.apache.coyote.Constants.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER` to `true` under `systemproperties`, but AS still overrides the HTTP error message.

Comment: Don't. It's simply a bad idea to use unregistered status codes, or to rely on the reason phrase.

Comment: That's not true in all cases. They may have a good reason for it - eg. proxy eats other HTTP headers somewhere on the way.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a mistake in JBoss documentation, the correct property name is:

```
org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER
```

So in the standalone you should have something like this:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the REST service is interpretted using RestEasy.

That provides a nice feature of injecting a HTTP response object using [@Context](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html_single/#_Context):

> The @Context annotation allows you to inject instances of javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders, javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo, javax.ws.rs.core.Request, javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse, javax.servlet.ServletConfig, javax.servlet.ServletContext, and javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext objects.

```
@Path("/")
public class MyService {
    @Context org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpResponse response;

    @GET @Path("/") public void myMethod(){
        response.sendError(499, "The file was censored by NSA.") 
    }
}
```

But maybe you should rather consider using a proprietary HTTP header:

```
        response.getOutputHeaders().putSingle("X-MyApp-Error", 
              "499 Our server is down and admin is on holiday. Mañana.");
```